# Removing directory in python almost always causes the folder to 'lock' and be un-removeable due to a permission error

Tags: python, windows, permissions

I'm using some simple code to remove a folder structure: One folder that has multiple subfolders that are populated each time the script is run, each named 1, 2, 3, etc. Inside each subfolder is a bunch of .png files. I'm running on Win10 Pro.

When using *any* method to remove the files and folders, windows "locks" the subfolder "1" but successfully deletes everything else. The folder becomes impossible to remove, asking permission from my own account or the Administrators group to delete it. The script cannot delete it and throws a PermissionError when it tries.

The folder disappears after a restart. Oddly, it also disappears after about 10 minutes of waiting and not doing anything.

I've used the following methods to remove the folders without success:

```
shutil.rmdir() normally

shutil.rmdir(onerror=fixpermission) with a function to clear read-only errors

os.chmod(file_path, 0o777) every file in the folder, os.remove() every file in the folder, then os.rmdir folders

literally just os.rmdir-ing every subfolder
```

Comment: A non-deterministic garbage collector exhibits non-deterministic behavior.

Comment: You are likely getting a sharing violation (32). When a directory is open as the working directory of a process, the system opens it without delete sharing. No one is allowed to delete the working directory of a process -- not even administrators.

Comment: In Windows, the right to delete the "1" directory is three fold. It's based either on the directory itself granting the caller delete access, or the parent directory granting the caller delete-child access, or the caller having SeRestorePrivilege enabled. In any case, deleting will fail if the directory is either not empty (access denied) or open as the working directory of a process (sharing violation).

Comment: In Windows, `os.chmod` merely sets/unsets the readonly file attribute (a category error; file attributes are not file permissions). So all you're doing with `os.chmod(file_path, 0o777)` is clearing the readonly attribute if it's set. You're not actually granting permission to read, write, and execute files and directories. Even if `chmod` were really implemented for Windows, the right to unlink a file or directory in the Unix model is based on write access to the parent directory (i.e. Windows delete-child access), and you're probably not calling this on the parent of the "1" directory.